# Is it better to use mysqli_real_escape_string (with mysqli) or placeholders (with PDO)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, sql-injection

Given this code:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_post = '$id'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    header('Location: 404.php');
    die();
} else {
    // Continue...
}
```

And this:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// New PDO...

$Ps = $Pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_post = :id');

$Ps->execute(array(':id', $id));

if ($Ps->rowCount() == 0) {
    header('Location: 404.php');
    die();
} else {
    // Continue...
}
```

Is there a best option to prevent SQL Injection or the are equivalent?

Comment: In the example the PDO one. However mysqli also supports prepared/parametrized statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The examples are apples to oranges. They can generally both be considered just as safe **if** using placeholders, which the former simply fails to do. Now, if asking about the use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` *or* placeholders (perhaps using such internally)..

Comment: @Philibobby, They are different questions

Comment: I've never delved into this that hard, but considering both provide a means to an end, it will mostly boil down to which one you prefer using.

Comment: @Jhecht And the observation that I would **not hire** a developer still insisting on `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of placeholders .. sure.

Comment: While I don't think this is a "good" question, and that the answers in the linked question do provide sufficient justification for the choice of approach, I do agree with the OP in that it is a [at least slight] different question.. so voting to re-open (to re-close), FWIW.

Comment: There's a sufficient amount of related question from which to infer a conclusion; [Why is using a mysql prepared statement more secure than using the common escape functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/732561), [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13569).

Answer (score 1):

Second option is the way to go.   Using `mysql_real_escape_string()` leaves open some space for sql injection using some exotic multibyte character. Ref: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Alternatively you can use prepared statment with `mysqli`

Comment: I am just curious, is there a way to do mysql injection, if $_GET['id'] is checked, before it is placed in query? E.g. expected value is number, and code checks if $id is number/numeric value? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know of any *current* vulnerabilities on `mysqli_real_escape_string` (which is *not* `mysql_real_escape_string`), assuming it is used with the same connection. Make sure to provide a reference for such a claim. (Also, placeholders *may* be internally implemented with escaping - but they are still a fundamentally better approach.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string second answer

Comment: what are you talkin about? mysql real escape string may be unsafe, read that question

Comment: By that very answer the same issue applies to PDO, with emulation - thanks for providing the link, which is a good read.

Comment: Yea, that is a very obscure edge case

Comment: @dynamic, it is mysqli_real_escape_string, but i really don't know is there any valuable difference. According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011899/mysqli-real-escape-string-should-i-use-it, there is no real difference between two functions, in terms of security.... However, could you (or someone else) explain, if, with few lines of code, developer check if $id is number/numeric value (he can specify length, too) -> can it by bypassed somehow? Thanks!