# PHP decode, alter and encode JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm guessing this has already been answered somewhere, but I can't find the solution I'm tearing my hair out. I have a JSON array stored in MySQL like this:

`[{"ip":"8.8.8.8","name":"Bob"},{"ip":"","name":""},{"ip":"","name":""},{"ip":"","name":""}]`

I want to replace the "ip" and "name" of a specific object. So I set `$slot_num` to something like 0 and try to alter the values and `UPDATE` the database. The SELECT clause below should be fine because it's used several times elsewhere.

```
//Recieves POST info such as ip=1.1.1.1&group=204&slot=3&name=help
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$group_id = $_POST['group'];
$slot_num = $_POST['slot'] -1; //PHP receives slot num increased by 1. IE- $slot_num 1 would be array[0]
$name = $_POST['name'];

if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `open_groups` WHERE `group_id` = $group_id")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $slot_ar = json_decode($row['players'], true);
    //Check if array has correct number slots
    if($slot_num => count($slot_ar) || !is_int($slot_num)){
        die('Injection attempt');
    }

    $slot_ar[$slot_num]['ip'] = $ip;
    $slot_ar[$slot_num]['name'] = $name;
    $players = json_encode($slot_ar);
    $players = $mysqli->real_escape_string($players);
    if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE `open_group` SET players = '$players' WHERE group_id = $group_id")) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
        exit;
    }
    if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `occupied`(`ip`, `group`) VALUES ('$ip', '$group_id')")) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success";
}
else echo $mysqli->error;
```

Am I accessing the array incorrectly or something?

### Fixed code

```
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$group_id = $_POST['group'];
$slot_num = $_POST['slot']; //PHP receives slot num increased by 1. IE- $slot_num 1 would be array[0]
$name = $_POST['name'];

if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `open_groups` WHERE `group_id` = $group_id")) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$slot_ar = json_decode($row['players'], true);
//Check if array has correct number slots
if($slot_num-1 >= count($slot_ar) || !is_numeric($slot_num)){
    echo "Injection attempt";
    exit;
}
$slot_ar[$slot_num-1]['ip'] = "$ip";
$slot_ar[$slot_num-1]['name'] = "$name";
$players = json_encode($slot_ar);
$players = $mysqli->real_escape_string($players);
if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE `open_groups` SET players = '$players' WHERE `group_id` = $group_id")) {
    echo "Update error";
    exit;
}
if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `occupied`(`ip`, `group`) VALUES ('$ip', '$group_id')")) {
    echo "Occupied error";
    exit;
}
echo "Success";
}
else echo "Fail";
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned what exactly is the problem.

Comment: You are not escaping `$players` anywhere, thus you have a syntax error and likely a SQL injection vulnerablity.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Wouldn't it be better to escape $name and $ip, not $player? Also, if you want to consider injection you need to check that $_POST['num'] isn't higher than the amount of places in the json array else people will create new entries through injection.

Comment: I escape `$name`, which I added to the question. The problem is that the data doesn't get changed in the db.

Comment: @CharlesForest No! The whole JSON string needs to be escaped, not just some of the indexes. It's true that `$slot_num` could be higher than it should be, and that should probably be guarded against, but that's not nearly as dangerous an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alexander, I'll fix both those issues.

Comment: I've updated my code with new, complete code. All I get for a return from calling this is "a blank string." Wha???

Comment: Also, if it helps, using Firebug I can check that my request contains valid info like `ip=1.1.1.1&group=204&slot=3&name=help`

Comment: DANGER : I just thought about this but what if the $slot sent is a string? You need to check that it's indeed an integer value. (Else it would go in the Json array and work through a foreach loop)

Comment: Solved it myself.. it was a combination of small mistakes and errors not reporting. The `is_int()` function was stopping my code every time and not outputting the error from `die()`, it finally did when I just replaced it with a basic `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape $players because json array is full of quotations so when you are inserting it into database using a query, mysql would have trouble in executing and understanding it.
also try to place variables inside single quotes after escaping it. Try this:

```
$players = $mysqli->real_escape_string($players);
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `open_group` SET players = '$players' WHERE group_id = '$group_id' ");
```

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I escaped $players in first line of my code, how can it be valnerable to SQL Injection? are you sure? can you provide an example?

Comment: Never mind, guess I just went blind for a second. Have an up-vote then!

Comment: I actually liked the warning from @AlexanderO'Mara. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: @CharlesForest He's using MySQLi's `real_escape_string`, which is decent enough. Variable binding is usually better though.

Comment: "Decent Enough" != Good. I changed the question reference, my bad on that one.

Comment: I've added single quotes to the UPDATE clause but no success!

Comment: @CharlesForest if you read the answer to your question, it says "The fact that you use single quotes (' ') around your variables inside your query is what protects you against this"    
so this code is Good, don't worry it tested it in several places

Comment: @Snailer Try debugging your query:
if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE `open_group` SET players = '$players' WHERE group_id = '$group_id' "))
echo $mysqli->error;

Comment: @Snailer What is the output now?

Answer (score 2):

As AlexanderO'Mara pointed out, you really should go with `bind_param()` over `mysqli_escape_string()` which has been proven unreliable on some occasions.  I use PDO statement so this is untested.

Source : [mysqli real escape string, should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011899/mysqli-real-escape-string-should-i-use-it)

```
$slot_num = $_POST['num'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// Initial select
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `open_groups` WHERE `group_id` = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('d', $group_id);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->errno) {
  die("Error : " . $stmt->error);
}

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $slot_ar = json_decode($row['players'], true); //Get JSON array

    // Make sure $slot_num isn't bigger than desired
    if($slot_num > count($slot_ar) || !is_int($slot_num)){
        die('Injection attempt');
    }
    // Store new variables in the array
    $slot_ar[$slot_num]['ip'] = "$ip";
    $slot_ar[$slot_num]['name'] = "$name";

    // encode the new $players
    $players = json_encode($slot_ar);

    // new SQL query
    $sql = "UPDATE `open_group` SET players = ? WHERE group_id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sd', $players, $group_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->errno) {
      die("Error : " . $stmt->error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you actually read your SO link?
at the end of answer it says : "or there will be no difference between PDO and mysql_escape_string in terms of acting for some extremely rare encodings.'

Comment: Skimmed it, my bad on that one. I changed the link.

Comment: Then in your new link, it said: "The fact that you use single quotes (' ') around your variables inside your query is what protects you against this" which is why i used, believe me my code is safe i made many researches on it

Comment: The kind of mistakes that leads to having unprepared statements insecure are the kind of mistakes I'd expect someone who doesn't protect himself against SQL injection in the first place to make. You're right though, your code is safe. I +1ed it.

Comment: Well, you are right too. Sometimes it's better to not dig the code and use prepared functions!

Comment: `is_int` was giving me trouble. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php.. it doesn't work on strings!